# (iOS 11.2.5) apple-mobile-web-app-capable breaks <input type="file"> workaround?

Tags: ios, safari, iphone-standalone-web-app

`iOS 11.2.5` has broken the image capture button `<input type="file">` for home screen (launch) icon, running in standalone mode (web capable mobile apps)...

Test case:- `capture.html`

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<input type="file">
```

**To reproduce**:

open [`capture.html`](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Mehuge/ee20ebe3a5ee377776ec397a76f9ea72/raw/994687aa44e25d49de01d437b583fd47c84e07fb/capture.html) in mobile safari, add to home screen, then open from home screen icon. Press choose file, select camera.

Camera opens with just a black view.

If I open `capture.html` in mobile safari (not from home screen icon) and use camera, it works.

If I remove `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` from `capture.html` and repeat the process of adding a home screen icon, the camera works correctly.

**Question**:

Does anyone have a workaround for this issue whilst retaining standalone mode (which is essential for a mobile app)?

**References**:

[1]: [apple-mobile-web-app-capable reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)

**EDIT**

Logged as a bug with Apple (id 36820143), who have since closed it `CLOSED DUPLICATE OF 35542231:CLOSED`.  So hopefully it will be fixed in the next update (fingers crossed).

Answer (score 2):

This has now been fixed in iOS 11.3 beta 1. :)

Release notes:

> **Safari Resolved Issues**
>
> - WebApps saved to the home screen and webpages
>   in SafariViewController can now use the camera to capture images.
>   (35542231)

https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=ios-11.3-sdk-rn

Comment: I like the "can now use" as if "ooh aren't we nice for adding this feature" when in fact it was working perfectly fine until they broke it in 11.2.5 :)